# I can't write data to more then one client applet

Tags: java, c++, sockets

I have a problem.  I am developing a applet that connects to a C++ server. For some reason when I launch a second applet in a new IE8 window I cannot write to it but I can still read.  Any text going to the second client applet is not getting through. I signed the jar file for my applet and can run it with IE8.  I am using Windows 7 with JCreator for my Java.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

#### HTML

```
<html> 
<head> 
</head> 
<body bgcolor="000000"> 
<center> 
<applet 
    archive="javafree.jar"
    code="javafree.class"
    width="800"
    height="500"> 
<param name="player" value="scar" /> 
</applet> 
</center> 
</body> 
</html>
```

#### Code

```
socket = new Socket( "localhost", 4000 ); 
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); 
out = new PrintStream( socket.getOutputStream(), true); 
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(classlink.socket.getInputStream())); 
if( in.ready() ) { 
    gametext += "<br><font color='#7DE5FF'>" + in.readLine() + "</font><br>"; 
    classlink.textman.setText(gametext); 
}
```

Comment: *"Any suggestions would be appreciated."*  1) Post a link where we can see the applet failing.  2) Failing that, post the HTML source that launches the applet.  3) Post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) of applet code that shows the stated behavior.  Why is the applet signed?

Comment: In future please do not put HTML & code into comments, instead edit them directly into the question (as I did above).  Check my edits carefully and if correct, delete the corresponding comments.

Comment: the applet and Cpp code is very large but I will post it. I just wanted to know if it was possible and maybe even get some working source as an example. I signed the JAR since I got some permission denied errors because it used sockets but signing the JAR fixed it. The above code was stripped of debugging code and such. BTW the part where I read data is in a "runable" THREAD

Answer (score 0):

You obviously overwrite your input stream with something not related to *this* socket (`classlink` suggests something class-level, static?) here:

```
in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(
        socket.getInputStream())); 
...
in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(
        classlink.socket.getInputStream()));
```